# How does HTTPS help websites under DoS attacks

Tags: tls, denial-of-service

From time to time one of the websites I browse regularly becomes a victim of a DoS/DDoS attack and usually they solve the problem by switching to https. I cant see the connection between the attack and the defense? TLS encrypts the connection what does this have to do with the number of connections that consume the server's resources?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only reason switching to HTTPS might help is if the attack is focused on only HTTP. There is no inherent DOS protection in HTTPS. In contrary, you could probably tie up the resources of the server with HTTPS with even less efforts if you start with a minimal SSL handshake so that the server has something to do but never continue with the SSL handshake after the server has sent its response.

Comment: How does it help if the attack was targeting HTTP?

Comment: If this an application level DOS attack like [slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_%28software%29) it will not affect HTTPS connection because these are on another port (assuming you have HTTP disabled completely). Of course it does not matter if it is a lower level DOS attack which just eats all available bandwidth.

Comment: an other port! that's what I didn't think of.. so next time my website becomes under attack I can order the web server to use port 22222 and email all my customers to access the site using the url:22222 or simply switch to https. What stops the attacker from attacking the new port?

Comment: If the attacker knows the new HTTP port it can attack it too, of course. If the attacker uses a HTTP only attack tool it will not succeed against HTTPS because this is not only a different port but also a different protocol, i.e you can't just use slowloris against port 443 (HTTPS) and hope it will work.

Comment: Is it that difficult to write an other tool for HTTPS? it's still a handshake mechanism unless you are suggesting the attacker is just a script kiddie

Comment: It's not really hard to write a DOS tool for TLS connections. It's probably enough to open a TCP connection, send a TLS ClientHello and then just keep the connection open.

Comment: TLS is even easier to attack usually, because establishing a new connection takes a lot more resources on the server than HTTPS! With THC SSL DOS one could take down a decent server from a home connectionhttps://code.google.com/p/sslyze/wiki/ThcSslDOS While renegotiation is usually disabled at the server nowadays, it is easy to create something that works without!

Comment: Hmm. Universally, DDOS attacks I've experienced simply involve flooding the host with packets, usually from a [DNS or NTP amplification attack](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-017A). Changing server ports would do nothing to mitigate against this attack vector.

Comment: There are several kinds of DOS attacks (and not all of them are DDOS). Simple flooding attacks like NTP or DNS amplification can often be filtered at the router, while application level attacks like slowloris not.

Answer (score 10):

Two things might make a difference here:

- If you switch from HTTP to HTTPS, you're switchings ports and protocols. It's effectively a different site. So the attacker would have to modify his attack to target the HTTPS site instead. Many DDoS attacks aren't nearly that sophisticated, so switching protocols could be all it takes.
- HTTPS requires more complexity on the client side than HTTP. Many bots used for this type of attack aren't particularly advanced, and HTTPS could be beyond the capability of the code in use.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few poorly thought out answers on here. A DDoS can be one of a few different attacks, all using numbers to overwhelm a site:

- Page generation attacks. Make the server(s) generate CPU-expensive pages for lots of users in a way that can't be cached. This slows the whole thing down.
- Flood attacks to fill SYN queues
- Bandwidth exhaustion

They don't "fill up" port 80 and leave the rest of the server and network alone.

Given that HTTP and HTTPS are *usually* served from the same machine, in the same network, behind the same routers... There is zero protection afforded from just making HTTPS available. It *is* a different port but so what?

The only case in which that will make a difference is if you're getting page-generation attacks on HTTP and to work around it, you disable :80 HTTP and *only* use :443 HTTPS. But:

- This breaks it for all your users (and Google) who use port 80. Wasn't that the goal the attacker wanted?
- 301 redirecting them automagically will (likely) redirect the attack
- Even if it doesn't DDoSes aren't hard to change. They're remote controlled computers. An attacker can easily change the order.

This won't help with network flood attacks. This *might* temporarily<sup>(for the same reasons as above)</sup> help with bandwidth exhaustion.

If you want to protect against a DDoS you *hide* the servers that are generating the pages (so attackers can't communicate with it directly) and you use a very large, very robust network of balanced proxy servers. This is essentially what CloudFlare is, on a global scale.

Comment: I think that in the comment that the server can switch ports, the assumption is that the server kills existing connections, stops the service on port 80, then restarts on the new port, thereby stopping the attack the way it was started.

Comment: It's analogous to stopping burglars by moving your door to the right. That HTTPS is a fairly standard means it's not even security by obscurity.

Comment: I completely agree, but for an automated DDoS attack, that "move to the right" can be what is needed to get back up and running. I've seen it before (done it myself) and it is a quick and dirty way to get services running again. The OP asked why it is used, and this is why: it sometimes works.

Answer (score 4):

HTTPS uses a different port than regular web sites, hence many DDOS attacks that are attacking a web site directly via port 80 will get no response from a site expecting (and only responding to) HTTPS ports (443 instead of port 80)